Python selenium webdriver.chrome issue
I have a code using these libraries
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Point, Polyline, Polygon
import datetime
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from getpass import getpass

I did a
pip install -r requirements.txt 

but I still get this error with loading the chromedriver below:
PS E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2> python .\marswaitforlogin.py                                                                   
enter in a ZULU time 00:00 -> 23:59 (15:10) for 3:10pm                                                                          
14:30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2\marswaitforlogin.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  File "E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__    
    self.service.start()
  File "E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
  File "E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 208, in _start_process 
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "E:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "E:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
PS E:\code\esri\FissionStaking2> 

any idea what I am missing?

This type of problem can occur when Python's subprocess module runs external executables:OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. First you need to check your programming environment, is your python 32-bit version? This problem is usually caused by using 64-bit Python, in which case the solution is to reinstall the 32-bit Python version. You may want to check if you import a C++ library dll. Generally speaking, it is because the number of python bits is not the same as the number of dll bits, dll is 32-bit, and python is 64-bit. Check yourself to see if these two parts correspond. Also, if you are using Anaconda to manage the environment, it may be possible to install a 32-bit version of python, but anaconda and other environments are using a 64-bit version. If you install it once with the original 32-bit python pip, all python programs will not run (and anaconda's python core will fail). The solution is to delete the python folder of the pip installation path, generally in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python, which the python folder can be deleted. I hope it was helpful.

Ok thanks Shen Ill give that a try , also this is after my machine was updated win10 -> win 11 Ill uninstall and reinstall python 3.10.11
